# Rolling minimum, fixed starting point

Tags: r

Ok so I want to calculate the rolling minimum value in a data frame, roll down the column. So far I am unable to fix the starting point and roll to the end of the series. I have tried:

```
mins <- c(10,5,6,10,6,6,7,8,2,12)
roll.min.expected <- c(10,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,2)
df <- data.frame(mins,roll.min.expected)
rollapplyr(df$mins, length(nrow(df)), min, partial = TRUE)
```

This is the expected output:

```
   mins roll.min.expected
1    10                10
2     5                 5
3     6                 5
4    10                 5
5     6                 5
6     6                 5
7     7                 5
8     8                 5
9     2                 2
10   12                 2
```

It prints the minimum until the next minimum is found

Comment: Isn't this just `cummin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `Reduce` with the option `accumulate=T`:

```
Reduce(min,mins,accumulate=T)
 [1] 10  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  2  2
```

Or more simply, as @Henrik mentioned in a comment, using the `cummin` function which returns the cumulative minimum:

```
cummin(mins)
[1] 10  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  2  2
```